# Makefile and pid files

Tags: make, gnu-make

I have some convenience rules in a Makefile that depends on pid files, but sometimes the pid files are there when the processes aren't. What's a good pattern to work around this in make?

For example, If i need to run something in qemu (build have complex multiarch requirements):

```
$(QPID):
    qemu-system... -pidfile "$(QPID)" ...
```

which works fine and only starts qemu once and gets shutdown beautifully on most systems, and all rules which depends on a specific type of vm only needs to depend on the correct pidfile variable. But for systemd being unable to properly signal user processes on shutdown reasons i don't want to get into because it always devolve into a flamewar... let's just accept: Those pidfiles lies during system reboots and I have to deal with it somehow.

It would be trivial to check the pidfile contents to see if the pid even exists. But `make` only cares about the file existing or not. What would be a good pattern to work around this?

Comment: If you're concerned about pid files not getting cleaned up across a reboot, just store them in an ephemeral filesystem like `/tmp` or `/run/user/$UID/`. Since those are in-memory filesystems, they don't persist across reboots.

Comment: @larsks i'm dealing with that on another question on systemd that is now a nasty flamewar... but your idea actually is very good (i mean, I still have my VMS SIGKILLed for no good reason, but at least solve THIS problem here). ...hum, only that now `make` have to manage something outside of the project file tree :(

Comment: all those makefiles inherit from a central one which manage vms in a rule dependency tree using each project's `.vm` dir. the image is downloaded, vdisk created, and pidfile stored all in that dir with common file names.